# infinitely loop jQuery chaining

Tags: jquery

I'm wondering if it's possible to keep similar format and set an infinite loop for simple jQuery chain animations like the below.

```
  $('.learnwhat').delay(500).fadeIn(1500);
  $('.learnwhat').delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
  $('.seeresults').delay(5000).fadeIn(1500);
  $('.seeresults').delay(500).fadeOut(500);
  $('.personalsolution').delay(9000).fadeIn(1500);
  $('.personalsolution').delay(500).fadeOut(500);
```

Comment: Are we supposed to imagine the markup?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu The markup is hardly relevant

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I'm just doing simple fadeIns? You want to see the content?

Comment: @CamC. Can you check my answer below if you expect a one like this

Comment: @aruna Ok - thanks for following up! It's not working for me....

Comment: @CamC. Any error or working differently?

Comment: Does not work - gives error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )' at '  animateFade($('.learnwhat'), [[500, 1500], [2000, 500]);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most jQuery animations accept a `callback` as a last parameter. Whatever you put there is called upon completion of the animation. All you need to do is name your animations by placing them in variables and calling them from the animation callback. Generic example:

```
var looping = function() {
   $('.learnwhat').delay(500).fadeIn(1500, looping());
}
```

The above should work. If it doesn't it's because the outside scope is not available inside the function scope, but you can always use `window.looping` and (`window.looping()`). In order not to pollute the `window` object, you should create a single object containing all your functions:

```
var window.myLoops = {
    loop_1:function() {
       $('.learnwhat').delay(500).fadeIn(1500, window.myLoops.loop_2());
    },
    loop_2:function() {
       $('.learnwhat').delay(500).fadeIn(500, window.myLoops.loop_1());
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll need to start them, by calling once: `window.myLoops.loop_1();`

Important: Don't expect two loops of equal duration to remain in sync. If you want to sync two animations you want to either place them both in the same function or chain their functions in one loop by calling each function from the other function's callback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `callback` of `jQuery` animation and can use a `generic` method as below to achieve this to reduce the code.

```
function animateFade(elm, timers, cb) {
     var index = 0;
     var animateFn = function() {
       if(timers.length > index) {
          var timer = timers[index++];
          elm.delay(timer[0]).fadeIn(timer[1], animateFn);
       } else if(cb && typeof cb === 'function') {
          cb();
       }
     };

     animateFn();
  }

  // Change the timer values here
  animateFade($('.learnwhat'), [[500, 1500], [2000, 500]);
  animateFade($('.seeresults'), [[5000, 1500], [500, 500]);
  animateFade($('.personalsolution'), [[9000, 1500], [500, 500]);

  // or even if you want to chain them one after another
  animateFade($('.learnwhat'), [[500, 1500], [2000, 500], function() {
     animateFade($('.seeresults'), [[5000, 1500], [500, 500], function() {
        animateFade($('.personalsolution'), [[9000, 1500], [500, 500]);
     });
  });
```

Comment: I believe the animations timers should be reduced when placing them inside callback trees with the duration of the animation they have been placed into. Aside from that, using `animate` as a variable name? It will collide on half of the websites it runs and it's almost impossible to debug/reproduce.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, I have changed this to `animateFn`. Yes, op can reduce the timers. I have mentioned this in the comment.